# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" Grails - IntelliJUltimate

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, slf4j

Build it via IntelliJ

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgebw.png)

I tried adding the dependencies slf4j-jdk12 and change the java versions!

i can start an application which i build via the CLI with no problem "grails run-app"
but in IntelliJ it throws the same problem as here

Comment: It looks like you are using some version of Java less than version 17 and you are trying to load a class with major version number 61 (Java 17).  I don't think Java supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Set Project SDk to compatible Java version. Try using 11 JDK for example:
[image]

Verify that modules uses the same JDK:
[image]

Also make sure **Gradle JVM** uses the same JDK:
[image]

Comment: Thank u !   i simply downloaded the "BellSoft Liberica  11" (not sure if thats a problem)
i can now run the App (no Problem messages) i can create classes (like Controllers etc) but then it still throws the (warning?)  - SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". -

Comment: Why do i get this Error after all? i mean an older JVM works better then a newer one? Why? is that related to Grails ? trying to find some tutorials for JVM/Linux etc but even Tutorials for seeting up System enviroment jvm is rare...